# Numpy applying a condition on each element of an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, valueerror

python begginer here. I've got a question which is probably super simple but I cant figure it out.

Lets say I've got a numpy array:
`a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])`

And I want to multiply each element by 2, but limit the result to a maximum of, say, 6. So my result would be an array `([2,3,6,6,6])`

However, when I do:
`b = min(6, a * 2)`

I get this error:
`ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

I've been doing some reading around and I can understand why a.any() or a.all() are required but i cant figure out how to implement this. I can avoid the error by looping across `a` and passing the condition over each item individually, however this seems very inefficient. This is a simplified version of my actual array which has a shape of (27,360,720), so looping over every single element simply doesnt sound right. Is there a nice solution?

Comment: try `np.minimum(6, a*2)`.

Comment: Well, that was embarasingly simple. Thanks.